# wifi access point with wicd?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot, wicd

How can I make a wifi access point with wicd?

I have a wired connection at laptop, and would like to deliver wifi to my android phone.

So in wicd I press Network -> create an ad hoc network, which as I understand makes a wifi network. I can't see it in my phone.

When I've been using network manager, it is called hotspot there, and I had to connect to it myself in order to deliver it. So I press connect to my own wifi. But wicd then turns off my wired connection. And I'm stuck and authentication phase.

I'm on kubuntu, 13.10 has some bug in network manager, so I switched to wicd.

This might be related: "does wicd allows controlling two interfaces at the same time? No" ([source](https://answers.launchpad.net/wicd/+faq/1868)) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The no wicd, but wicd complient solution is found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html).

**Edit**

I can connect, but it woundn't let my phone to the internet.